# Qt5 & QtQuick2 - transparent main window

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to create a simple Qt UI with a frameless window and rounded corners. Starting from a new project with the *QtQuick 2 Application* template, my code looks like this:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;

    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/qtquick-test/main.qml"));
    viewer.setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    radius: 10
    color: "red"

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: And this is the result]

What I wan't to do is get rid of the white corners, by making the main window transparent. However, as far as I can tell there is no way in Qt5 to do this, because we don't have stylesheets, etc and I am not using a QtWidget. Should I use a QtWidget?

Btw, I'm new to Qt and Qt5.

Comment: Looks like this might be resolved in 5.1 by creating a widget as a container window using `QWidget::createWindowContainer()`. See the [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25643) and the [commit](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,44285). Am going to try and compile 5.1 from source and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @andrewrjones You can answer and accept your own question.

Comment: @MottiStrom Never found the answer, and moved on to using something else instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me under Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    color: "transparent"

    Rectangle {
        color: "brown"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus! That is pretty much it. On Mac, I just had to add `visible: true` to the Window, and `radius: 10` to the Rectangle, and I get exactly what I wanted. Uploaded this as an example project to GitHub: https://github.com/andrewrjones/qt-transparent-main-window

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out. :) And thanks for mentioning me in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this late like I did. For C++ and Python atleast you have to specify the widget attribute `WA_TranslucentBackground` to be able to make your background transparent.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use
`viewer.setMask()`
 in order to tell the qt widget that displays the qml where to draw and where not to....

I've used mostly rectangular masks but setMask accepts a QRegion which i think supports more complicated forms and even bitmap mask

Answer (score -2):

Set the background clear color to have an alpha of 0 on your application viewer:

```
viewer.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: This does not work with Qt 5.0. You get a black background, not a transparent one.